# Why geojson and polyline return different position with same coordinate (Leaflet)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I'am learning the leaflet.js. I made three lines with same coordinates.

Two of them are included in Geojson with different weight and color, and then I used Polyline to create the third one, but it returns to another position, that make me confusied.

So there are my code

```js
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([45.73, -104.99], 1);
  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo(mymap);

   var cor = [[58.44773, -28.65234], [53, -23.33496], [53, -14.32617]];
   var line =[ 
        {
           "type": "Feature",
           "geometry": {
               "type": "LineString",
               "coordinates": cor
           },
           "properties": {
               "ID": 'ID',
               "color": 'orange',
               "type" : 'type',
               "after" : false
           }
        },

        {
           "type": "Feature",
           "geometry": {
               "type": "LineString",
               "coordinates": cor
           },
           "properties": {
               "ID": 'ID',
               "color": 'black',
               "type" : 'type',
               "after" : true
           }
        }, 
      ];

var polyline = new L.geoJson(line, {
    style: function(layer){
      return {color:layer.properties.color,
                weight : !layer.properties.after? 10:1
              };
        }
}).addTo(mymap);

var offset = L.polyline(cor, {
            color: 'green',
          opacity:1         
          }).addTo(mymap);
```

```css
#mapid { height: 600px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="mapid"></div>
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s3dup7ez/6/

I didn't find the the raison, hope some helps, thanks

Comment: One of the APIs looks like it's expecting [lat, lon] and the other is expecting [lon, lat].

Comment: ... and there is some background at https://macwright.org/lonlat/